# Row actions not showing? Why?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, php, wp-list-table

I have constructed a `WP_List_Table` that displays on a custom theme page that I have built. I am having some trouble getting the row actions to display, despite me reviewing all the possible info on the Internet about WP_List_Table.

Any help would be great!

```
class Testimonials_List_Table extends WP_List_Table {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct( array(
    'singular'=> 'testimonial', //Singular label
    'plural' => 'testimonials', //plural label, also this well be one of the table css class
    'ajax' => false //We won't support Ajax for this table
   ) );
}

function get_bulk_actions() {
    $actions = array(
    'delete' => 'Delete'
    );
    return $actions;
}

function process_bulk_action() {
    if( 'delete'===$this->current_action() ) {
    wp_die('Items deleted (or they would be if we had items to delete)!');
   }  
}

function get_columns() {
return $columns= array(
    'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />', //Render a checkbox instead of text
    'name'=> 'Name',
    'company_name'=> 'Company Name',
    'company_url'=> 'Website URL',
    'testimonials_quote'=> 'Testimonial'
);
}

function column_name($item){
    $actions = array(
        'edit'      => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&testimonial=%s">Edit</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'edit',$item['ID']),
        'delete'    => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&testimonial=%s">Delete</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'delete',$item['ID']),
    );

    //Return the title contents
    return sprintf('%1$s <span style="color:silver">(id:%2$s)</span>%3$s',
        /*$1%s*/ $item['name'],
        /*$2%s*/ $item['ID'],
        /*$3%s*/ $this->row_actions($actions)
    );
}



function column_cb($item){
    return sprintf(
        '<input type="checkbox" name="%1$s[]" value="%2$s" />',
        /*$1%s*/ $this->_args['singular'],  //Let's simply repurpose the table's singular label ("movie")
        /*$2%s*/ $item['ID']                //The value of the checkbox should be the record's id
    );
}

function prepare_items() {
global $wpdb, $_wp_column_headers;
$screen = get_current_screen();
$wpdb->show_errors(); 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_testimonials"; 
$orderby = !empty($_GET["orderby"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["orderby"]) : 'ASC';
$order = !empty($_GET["order"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["order"]) : '';
    if(!empty($orderby) & !empty($order)){ $query.=' ORDER BY '.$orderby.' '.$order; }
    $totalitems = $wpdb->query($query); //return the total number of affected rows
    $perpage = 8;
    $paged = !empty($_GET["paged"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["paged"]) : '';
    if(empty($paged) || !is_numeric($paged) || $paged<=0 ){ $paged=1; }
    $totalpages = ceil($totalitems/$perpage);
    if(!empty($paged) && !empty($perpage)){
        $offset=($paged-1)*$perpage;
        $query.=' LIMIT '.(int)$offset.','.(int)$perpage;
    }
$this->set_pagination_args( array(
    "total_items" => $totalitems,
    "total_pages" => $totalpages,
    "per_page" => $perpage,
    ) );
$columns = $this->get_columns();
    $hidden = array();
    $sortable = $this->get_sortable_columns();
    $this->_column_headers = array($columns, $hidden, $sortable);
    $this->items = $wpdb->get_results($query);

}

function display_rows() {
$records = $this->items;
list( $columns, $hidden ) = $this->get_column_info();
if(!empty($records)){foreach($records as $rec){
    echo '<tr id="record_'.$rec->name.'">';
    foreach ( $columns as $column_name => $column_display_name ) {
        $class = "class='$column_name column-$column_name'";
        $style = "";
        if ( in_array( $column_name, $hidden ) ) $style = ' style="display:none;"';
        $attributes = $class . $style;
            $editlink  = '/test/wp-admin/themes.php?page=testimonials&tab=add_new_testimonial='.urlencode((int)$rec->id);
        switch ( $column_name ) {
           case "cb": echo '<td '.$attributes.'><input type="checkbox" /></td>';break;
           case "id": echo '<td '.$attributes.'>'.stripslashes($rec->id).'</td>';break;
           case "name": echo '<td '.$attributes.'><strong><a href="'.$editlink.'" title="Edit">'.stripslashes($rec->name).'</a></strong></td>'; break;
            case "company_name": echo '<td '.$attributes.'>'.stripslashes($rec->company_name).'</td>'; break;
                case "company_url": echo '<td '.$attributes.'>'.stripslashes($rec->company_url).'</td>'; break;
                case "testimonials_quote": echo '<td '.$attributes.'>'.stripslashes($rec->testimonials_quote).'</td>'; break;
        }
    }
    echo'</tr>';
    }}
    }


} // End WP_List_Table class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `display_rows()` you are using the following code to print the 'name' column:

```
echo '<td '.$attributes.'><strong><a href="'.$editlink.'" title="Edit">'.stripslashes($rec->name).'</a></strong></td>';
```

Nowhere do you call `column_name()`, which is the function you've defined to display the item's and row actions:

```
function column_name($item){
    $actions = array(
        'edit'      => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&testimonial=%s">Edit</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'edit',$item['ID']),
        'delete'    => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&testimonial=%s">Delete</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'delete',$item['ID']),
    );

    //Return the title contents
    return sprintf('%1$s <span style="color:silver">(id:%2$s)</span>%3$s',
        /*$1%s*/ $item['name'],
        /*$2%s*/ $item['ID'],
        /*$3%s*/ $this->row_actions($actions)
    );
}
```

See, for example, how the underlying `WP_List_Table` [does it](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4.1/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php#L829).

In fact, if you avoid over-riding the underlying class's `display_rows()` method then it will automatically use your `column_{$column_id}()` method (where it exists), to define the content of the column. This makes it much easier to maintain than your current switch statement.

Comment: Great! I like your idea of not over-riding `display_rows()`. What exact code do I need to remove to see an example of this in action?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @RobMyrick simply remove `display_rows()` from the code you have. Then define `column_foo()` to define the 'foo' column for a particular row. (e.g. `column_company_name()`). It is passed the item as an argument.